# Multiple background threads calling SetForegroundWindow() act as if they are all foreground threads at the same time

Tags: windows, winapi, background-foreground, setforegroundwindow

**Why does calling `SetForegroundWindow()` in multiple background threads act as if they are all foreground threads at the same time?**

In my understanding, calling `SetForegroundWindow()` after creating a window in a background thread will set the calling thread as the foreground thread. However, whenever another thread calls `SetForegroundWindow()`, then that thread becomes the foreground thread, and the previous foreground thread returns to the background.

I've tested 3 cases by clicking the title bar of a window and dragging it.

- Case 1 : A process with a single threaded message loop with multiple windows
- Case 2 : A process with multiple threaded message loops with one window per thread
- Case 3 : A process with multiple threaded message loop with one window per thread calling `SetForegroundWindow()` after creating each window

The results of each cases were:

- Case 1 : Any window is draggable with a single click.
- Case 2 : Any background window is set the the foreground but is not draggable with a click. I have to click twice on the window to perform dragging.
- Case 3 : Any window is draggable with a single click.

The reason why I express "as if they are all foreground threads" in my question is that case 3 *should* act the same as case 2 unless the clicked window is already in the foreground.

References I looked at are as follows:

- [Foreground and Background Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#foreground-and-background-windows)
- [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)
- [About foreground permission](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083)
- [About SetForegroundWindow and GetForegroundWindow](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161118-00/?p=94745)

[EDIT]

Here's the sample code that reproduces Case 2. If SetForegroundWindow is called for each windows in each thread, Case 3 is reproduced. Case 1 can be reproduced if SINGLETHREAD is defined.

```
#include <Windows.h>

HINSTANCE g_hInstance = nullptr;
HANDLE g_hEvent0 = nullptr;
HANDLE g_hEvent1 = nullptr;

//#define SINGLETHREAD

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND _hWnd, UINT _unMessage, WPARAM _wParam, LPARAM _lParam)
{
    switch (_unMessage)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
    
    return DefWindowProc(_hWnd, _unMessage, _wParam, _lParam);
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread0(LPVOID _lpParam)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW stWndClassExW0
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW),
        CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
        &WndProc,
        0,
        0,
        g_hInstance,
        nullptr,
        static_cast<HICON__*>(LoadImageW(nullptr, static_cast<const wchar_t*>(IDC_ARROW), static_cast<unsigned int>(IMAGE_CURSOR), 0, 0, static_cast<unsigned int>(LR_SHARED))),
        static_cast<HBRUSH__*>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)),
        L"MenuName",
        L"ClassName0",
        nullptr
    };

    ATOM usWindowClass0 = RegisterClassExW(&stWndClassExW0);

    HWND hWnd0 = CreateWindowExW(0,
                                 reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(usWindowClass0),
                                 L"0",
                                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                 0,
                                 0,
                                 1200,
                                 800,
                                 nullptr,
                                 nullptr,
                                 g_hInstance,
                                 nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hWnd0, SW_SHOW);

    //SetForegroundWindow(hWnd0);

    MSG msg{};

    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                break;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }

    SetEvent(g_hEvent0);

    return 0ul;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID _lpParam)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW stWndClassExW1
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW),
        CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
        &WndProc,
        0,
        0,
        g_hInstance,
        nullptr,
        static_cast<HICON__*>(LoadImageW(nullptr, static_cast<const wchar_t*>(IDC_ARROW), static_cast<unsigned int>(IMAGE_CURSOR), 0, 0, static_cast<unsigned int>(LR_SHARED))),
        static_cast<HBRUSH__*>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)),
        L"MenuName",
        L"ClassName1",
        nullptr
    };

    ATOM usWindowClass1 = RegisterClassExW(&stWndClassExW1);

    HWND hWnd1 = CreateWindowExW(0,
                                 reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(usWindowClass1),
                                 L"1",
                                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                 200,
                                 200,
                                 1200,
                                 800,
                                 nullptr,
                                 nullptr,
                                 g_hInstance,
                                 nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hWnd1, SW_SHOW);

    //SetForegroundWindow(hWnd1);

    MSG msg{};

    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                break;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }

    SetEvent(g_hEvent1);

    return 0ul;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE _hInstance,
                    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE _hPrevInstance,
                    _In_ LPWSTR _lpCmdLine,
                    _In_ int _nCmdShow)
{
    g_hInstance = _hInstance;

#ifdef SINGLETHREAD

    WNDCLASSEXW stWndClassExW0
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW),
        CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
        &WndProc,
        0,
        0,
        g_hInstance,
        nullptr,
        static_cast<HICON__*>(LoadImageW(nullptr, static_cast<const wchar_t*>(IDC_ARROW), static_cast<unsigned int>(IMAGE_CURSOR), 0, 0, static_cast<unsigned int>(LR_SHARED))),
        static_cast<HBRUSH__*>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)),
        L"MenuName",
        L"ClassName0",
        nullptr
    };

    ATOM usWindowClass0 = RegisterClassExW(&stWndClassExW0);

    HWND hWnd0 = CreateWindowExW(0,
                                 reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(usWindowClass0),
                                 L"0",
                                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                 0,
                                 0,
                                 1200,
                                 800,
                                 nullptr,
                                 nullptr,
                                 g_hInstance,
                                 nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hWnd0, SW_SHOW);

    WNDCLASSEXW stWndClassExW1
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW),
        CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
        &WndProc,
        0,
        0,
        g_hInstance,
        nullptr,
        static_cast<HICON__*>(LoadImageW(nullptr, static_cast<const wchar_t*>(IDC_ARROW), static_cast<unsigned int>(IMAGE_CURSOR), 0, 0, static_cast<unsigned int>(LR_SHARED))),
        static_cast<HBRUSH__*>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)),
        L"MenuName",
        L"ClassName1",
        nullptr
    };

    ATOM usWindowClass1 = RegisterClassExW(&stWndClassExW1);

    HWND hWnd1 = CreateWindowExW(0,
                                 reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(usWindowClass1),
                                 L"1",
                                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                 200,
                                 200,
                                 1200,
                                 800,
                                 nullptr,
                                 nullptr,
                                 g_hInstance,
                                 nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hWnd1, SW_SHOW);

    tagMSG stMSG{};

    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessageW(&stMSG, nullptr, 0, 0, static_cast<unsigned int>(PM_REMOVE)) != 0)
        {
            if (stMSG.message == static_cast<unsigned int>(WM_QUIT))
            {
                break;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&stMSG);
            DispatchMessageW(&stMSG);
        }
    }
#else

    g_hEvent0 = CreateEvent(nullptr, 0, 0, nullptr);
    g_hEvent1 = CreateEvent(nullptr, 0, 0, nullptr);

    DWORD dwThreadID0 = 0ul;
    DWORD dwThreadID1 = 0ul;

    HANDLE hThread0 = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, &Thread0, nullptr, 0, &dwThreadID0);
    HANDLE hThread1 = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, &Thread1, nullptr, 0, &dwThreadID1);

    WaitForSingleObject(g_hEvent0, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(g_hEvent1, INFINITE);

#endif // SINGLETHREAD

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: @IInspectable what does that have to do with anything? There is no cross-process handling in this situation. There is only 1 process running, and it is not sharing windows with other processes. It is simply creating its own windows and bringing them into the foreground under various conditions.

Comment: @rem The fundamental issues are identical, regardless of whether you create a relationship across threads or processes.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't see any cross-thread issue here, either. Each thread has its own window(s), there is no parent/child relationship being made across threads.

Comment: @rem *"I don't see any cross-thread issue here, either."* - Neither do I. Then again, I don't see any code either. And while it's common that issue reports in prose tend to avoid talking about the specific detail that's causing the issue, I left a link to an article that is highly likely to be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and reference IInspectable. I added sample code that reproduces the phenomenon I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and edition Remy Lebeau. I added sample code that reproduces the phenomenon I mentioned.